# Image rotated but thumbnail is not

Tags: c#, image-processing, exif

I am trying to rotate the image based on EXIF tag. I am able to handle the rotation of image successfully but the thumbnail in windows explorer is still upside down. The image when opened is absolutely fine. Verified the corrected orientation [here.](http://regex.info/exif.cgi) The problem with the following code is that the EXIF data does not seem to have any information about thumbnail orientation. What I want is:

1. If there is thumbnail orientation available, rotate the thumbnail and update image's metadata for thumbnail orientation.
2. If there is no thumbnail orientation information available, rotate the thumbnail and add image's metadata for thumbnail orientation.

The code I am using is:

```
public static RotateFlipType RotateImageByExifOrientationData(Image img, string oldFileName, string sourceFilePath, out string newFileName)
{    
    int orientationId = 0x0112;//Image orientation
    int thumbnailOrientationId = 0x5029;//Thumbnail orientation
    var fType = RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone;

    if (img.PropertyIdList.Contains(orientationId))
    {
        var pItem = img.GetPropertyItem(orientationId);
        //Get the orientation
        fType = GetRotateFlipTypeByExifOrientationData(pItem.Value[0]);
        if (fType != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
        {
            img.RotateFlip(fType);

            // Read orientation tag. Update to normal so that the other clients(image viewer or browser) will not rotate the rotated image.                                      
            // Force value to 1
            pItem.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1);
            img.SetPropertyItem(pItem);
            PropertyItem thumbnailItem;
            if (img.PropertyIdList.Contains(thumbnailOrientationId))
            {
                //If thumbnail metadata is available, update it.
                thumbnailItem = img.GetPropertyItem(thumbnailOrientationId);
                thumbnailItem.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1);
                img.SetPropertyItem(thumbnailItem);
            }
            else
            {
                //If thumbnail metadata is not available, add appropriate metadata.
                thumbnailItem = img.PropertyItems[0];
                thumbnailItem.Id = thumbnailOrientationId;
                thumbnailItem.Type = 2;
                thumbnailItem.Value = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)1);
                thumbnailItem.Len = thumbnailItem.Value.Length;
                img.SetPropertyItem(thumbnailItem);
            }
            newFileName = "Rotated_" + oldFileName;
            string targetFilePath = sourceFilePath + newFileName ;
            ImageFormat targetFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            img.Save(targetFilePath, targetFormat);
            File.Delete(sourceFilePath + oldFileName);//Delete old file.
        }
    }
    return fType;
}
```

Comment: My deep suspicion is that a thumbnail just does not follow EXIF tags, so after the changing the EXIF metadata, you have to regenerate thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

is an old question, but after some research, I noticed that even after removing the orientation of the Image (0x0112) and the orientation of the thumbnail (0x5029), when trying to generate the thumbnail again, the same orientation remained. So I checked that some JPGs have the thumbnail "embedded" in bytes. so after removing the bytes (0x501B), I was able to generate the thumbnail correctly.

Simple code shows:

```
    var rotateImage = Image.FromStream(fileStream);
    switch (degree)
    {
        case eRotateImagem.Degree_90:
            rotateImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
            break;
        case eRotateImagem.Degree_180:
            rotateImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            break;
        case eRotateImagem.Degree_270:
            rotateImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
            break;
    }

    int orientationId = 0x0112; //Image orientation
    int thumbnailOrientationId = 0x5029; //Thumbnail orientation
    int thumbnailBytes = 0x501B; //Thumbnail bytes

    if (rotateImage.PropertyIdList.Contains(orientationId))
    {
        rotateImage.RemovePropertyItem(orientationId);
    }
    if (rotateImage.PropertyIdList.Contains(thumbnailOrientationId))
    {
        rotateImage.RemovePropertyItem(thumbnailOrientationId);
    }
    if (rotateImage.PropertyIdList.Contains(thumbnailBytes))
    {
        rotateImage.RemovePropertyItem(thumbnailBytes);
    }
```